# MS Access: Method to process SQL without using RecordSource

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I would like to be able to find the last record in a table easily for SQL INSERT INTO table statement. I was hoping there would be a MS Access object or function which could read a SQL statement without requerying the whole context just to find specific counts or records. As I have been programming the only code I know that reads SQL is a recordset, is there a dummy copy or source you could just read without repointing the record to another? Otherwise, I need a way to access the table in VBA and count all records with a method. If this is not code yet is should be, this would make it so easy to get around code dialects, other methods (unless you need to use form objects) if you know SQL.
I have tried several things, such as that cast a tbl variable but there would be a type mismatch.

This needs a last statement so I get the new record... I need to know how to get the last record in the table with a count.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO FormsHelpTable ([ID], [HelpTitle], [Comment]) VALUES " & _
                  "(" & (lastRecTbl + 1) & ", '" & Me.Text53 & "', '" & Me.Comment & "')", dbFailOnError
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM FormsHelpTable"
Me.Requery
```

Comment: It very unclear what you actually want to do ...

Comment: I need to find the last record and would like to do this without having to write several references to the object or casting problems. SQL would be an easy way around this searching for code, but I will edit to add the actual problem with referencing the code. Basically a variable that acts like a query or will read like one which today probably has to be pieced together in lines of code.

Comment: The function did not work in the context. Hmmm. (Thinking)

Comment: Says invalid argument in the function...? Now added Me.ID but that wont work either.

Comment: An AutoNumber is the way to have an incrementing ID, manually creating your own is a bad idea; what if two people did this at the same time?

Comment: DMax wont be the best method since autonumber wont start at the highest record in the table (because deletes).

Comment: I need to save several items from a form and this is the easiest way to do it. I suppose if they do the other would have a conflict because the primary key. I suppose a refresh before actually following through may prevent a problem.

Comment: It sounds like all you need is to bind the form to table FormsHelpTable. No SQL would then be needed.

Comment: Gustav please explain more of what you mean.

Comment: *"autonumber wont start at the highest record in the table (because deletes)"* - If you are suggesting that an AutoNumber column will re-use values from deleted rows then you are mistaken.

Comment: No not at all. The autonumber will just and skip over those deletes so the DMax is not that number, it is stored in the control of the table as it creates them.

Answer (score 0):

This worked to find the last record:
http://www.minnesotaithub.com/2013/08/count-records-vba-microsoft-access-2010/

Great code too.

Comment: If it is possible to use the save method in VBA and somehow choose what data to save and update/insert into the table then that would maybe work better... anyone have know how to with VBA/save?